# Excel IF clause - function not reading cell correctly

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

This is my code in an excel cell `U4`:

```
=IF(OR(E4="B",E4="C",E4="D",E4="M",E4="A"),"DC",IF(T4="WG","DC",IF(T4="IH","No DC","?")))
```

Cell `T4` reads "WG" with the given function below, which is supposed to assign `U4` "DC" regardless of the OR function in the beginning but its assigning "?"

This is whats in `T4`

```
=VLOOKUP(N4,DC_Matrix!K:Y,9,FALSE)
```

Any ideas why `U4` is not giving me DC?

Comment: Check what is being returned.  If I manually put `WG` in T4 it returns `DC` in U4.  You may find that the data that is being returned by the VLOOKUP has a space or other unprintable characters.

Comment: Thanks Scott, you're right! Cant believe I missed that

Comment: try TRIM(T4)='WG'

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Scott Craner - Formulas are working correctly; vlookup is just returning different data than expected.